# HTML First Step

Tags: html

Im using Visual Studio Code to work on an HTML website. When I complete the basic code entry it pops up as this (see picture). I tried multiple different ways to get the website to work but can't figure it out. Here's the code as well. Lmk any suggestions[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j3Iz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfnQF.png)

I have tried everything

Answer (score 0):

Well first check if the file is a html file. Once you are sure it is, try opening finder and going to the directory that ur projects in and double click the html file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the Live Preview VSCode extension, this is showing the directory of whatever folder is the current workspace.

It also seems the file is not saved as an HTML file, but rather a file with no extension. Make sure it is set as a `.html` file.

The file is in the `File` directory as shown in VSCode. Simply click that directory and it should pop up with your file.

A fool-proof solution is to find your HTML file in finder and double click it. It will open in a new window, although you will have to refresh the page manually whenever you make a change.